# Is there a way to fix Python Interpreter error in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pythoninterpreter

Has anybody seen this error while trying to to choose the python interpreter in VSCode?
[image]

I immediately get an error when trying to find an appropriate interpreter. Is there any way around this problem? I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling both VSCode and Python but nothing seems to work.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Did you install the recommended Python extensions?  It says you're in "restricted mode".

Comment: Yes, the extension was installed. But I managed to fix it thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_select-a-python-interpreter) first.

Please ensure that **python** and [**python extensions**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) are installed, and then select python interpreter(Ctrl+Shift+P then **Python: Select Interpreter**).

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the uninstalling, cleaning and reinstalling in the world which didn't fix it, for me eventually this fixed the issue:

Click **Restricted Mode** in the bottom-left corner and click **trust** to trust this window.

Now you can use Ctrl + Shift + P to select the Python interpreter and you won't get the error where nothing seems to point at the workspace restriction being the problem.